# Multithreaded Bash in while loop

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, while-loop, grep

I have the following Bash one liner which should iterate through all the files in the folder named *.xml , check if they have the below string, and if not, rename them to $.empty

```
find -name '*.xml'   | xargs -I{} grep -LZ "state=\"open\"" {} | while IFS= read -rd '' x; do mv "$x" "$x".empty ; done
```

this process is very slow, and when running this script in folders with over 100k files, it takes well over 15 minutes to complete. 
I couldn't find a way to make this process to run multithreadly. 
Note that in for loop im hitting the "too many arguments" errors, due to the large number of files.
Can anyone think of a solution ? 
Thanks ! 
Roy

Comment: Why do you think multithreaded would be faster?  Is your CPU core at 100%?  Your disk is the slow thing, change to SSD.

Comment: On thing that might make your script a bit faster is to make your `grep` as part of `find` command so creation of new shell and interprocess data transfer will be prevented.

Comment: @stark This command would be slow even if they weren't reading from disk.

Comment: You can try with xargs -P<number of logcal cores>, but, as said, the performance boost won't be great as it's a disk operation.

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using?

Comment: You could do the following:


`for file in $(grep -n -LZ "state=\"open\"" $(find . -name '*.xml') |sort -u)
do
mv ${file} ${file%%\.xml}.empty
done`

You may need to increase the 'ulimit' stack size to get the "grep -LZ "state=\"open\"" $(find . -name '*.xml')" to work though

Comment: @FinbarrO'Brien Please read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: @stark while running this, i get no CPU usage spike. This is a VM located on an SSD drive. 
{at}chepner GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest bottleneck in your code is that you are running a separate `mv` process (which is just a wrapper around a system call) to rename each file. Let's say you have 100,000 files, and 20,000 of them need to be renamed. Your original code will need 120,000 processes, one `grep` per file and one `mv` per rename. (Ignoring the 2 calls to `find` and `xargs`.)

A better approach would be to use a language than can access the system call directly. Here is a simple Perl example:

```
find -name '*.xml' | xargs -I{} grep -LZ "state=\"open\"" {} |
  perl -n0e 'rename("$_", "$_.empty")'
```

This replaces 20,000 calls to `mv` with a single call to `perl`.

The other bottleneck is running a single `grep` process for each file. Instead, you'd like to pass as many files as possible to `grep` each time. There is no need for `xargs` here; use the `-exec` primary to `find` instead.

```
find -name '*.xml' -exec grep -LZ "state=\"open\"" {} + |
  perl -n0e 'rename("$_", "$_.empty")'
```

The too many arguments error you were receiving is based on total argument length. Suppose the limit is 4096, and your XML files have an average name length of 20 characters. This means you should be able to pass 200+ files to each call to `grep`. The `-exec ... +` primary takes care of passing as many files as possible to each call to `grep`, so this code at most will require 100,000 / 200 = 500 calls to `grep`, a vast improvement.

Depending on the size of the files, it might be faster to read each file in the Perl process to check for the string to match. However, `grep` is very well optimized, and the code to do so, while not terribly complicated, is still more than you can comfortably write in a one-liner. This should be a good balance between speed and simplicity.

Comment: The second is a really nice and clean solution.